# Additional option to create an account after place an order

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, customer-account

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and often customers checkout as guest because they are involved in a process and do not want to create an account in the checkout. I want to set a second possibility on the success message page after place the order.
the customer is relaxed and maybe it's easier to get a new reg. customer then.
any help appreciated.

Comment: i does  not get  `I want to set a second possibility on the success message page after place the order. the customer is relaxed and maybe it's easier to get a new reg. customer then. any help appreciated.`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas.

1. Have you considered just adding a large button on your /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/success.phtml page with a link to your account registration page?
2. Maybe running a script for a pop-up would also work if you redirect your checkout/success page to the home page. At least the customer would have to interact with the pop-up unless they are running a blocker.
3. Make registration the only option.

Comment: I believe his goal is to associate the order with the account

Comment: Hi,
I want to create a second chance to register as a customer. Magento offers the function "create an account for later use" on the checkout page but most customers do not use this because they are mental bounded with the checkout process.
This was the reason for the idea to place a second possibility on the success page where the users are relaxed.

Comment: Magento offers the function "create an account for later use" on the checkout page but most customers do not use this because they are mental bounded with the checkout process.
This was the reason for the idea to place a second possibility on the success page where the users are relaxed.

@scot: yes, I have it. but in this case the customer have to fill out the complete form again - not fine. It would be great if the system use the details from the placed order.